# How to compute moments from an MGF explicitly?

Tags: self-study, moments, moment-generating-function

> Suppose the mgf $M_x(t)$ is defined, for a suitable neighbourhood of zero $(-\delta, \delta)$, as $$M_X(t) = \frac{9 e^{-t}}{(3 + 2t)^2}.$$  Find an expression for $\mathbb{E}_X[X^r]$ for $r=1,2,\ldots, .$

I have to multiply two Taylor expansions; however,  I do not know how to differentiate this product $r$ times with respect to $t$.

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain where your difficulty lies.

Answer (score 2):

**The entire point to using the mgf to compute moments is that you usually *don't* have to compute derivatives.**  Moreover, the exercise of expanding an mgf usually is purely mechanical, requiring no guessing or insight.  The following calculations are intended to exemplify a basic approach that works in many cases:

- Break the mgf into factors that can easily be expanded in power series (for instance, they match the mgfs of well-known distributions whose power series can be looked up);
- Multiply the corresponding power series.
- Pick out the coefficient of the $r^\text{th}$ power and multiply it by $r! = r(r-1)\cdots(2)(1)$: that's the $r^\text{th}$ moment.

---

The form of this particular mgf invites us to look at it as the product of two pieces: $9e^{-t}$ times $(3+2t)^{-2}$.  Both of these are simple and have familiar MacLaurin expansions (that is, Taylor series around $0$):

$$\eqalign{
9 e^{-t} &= 9\left(1 + \frac{-t}{1} + \frac{(-t)^2}{2} + \cdots + \frac{(-t)^n}{n!} + \cdots\right);\\
(3 + 2t)^{-2} &= 3^{-2}\left(1 + \frac{2}{3}t\right)^{-2} \\ &= 3^{-2}\left( 1 - 2\left(\frac{2}{3}t\right) + 3\left(\frac{2}{3}t\right)^2 + \cdots + \binom{-2}{k}\left(\frac{2}{3}t\right)^k + \cdots\right).}$$

This is a consequence of Newton's Binomial Theorem; the binomial coefficients are computed as

$$\binom{-2}{k} = \frac{(-2)(-3)\cdots(-2-k+1)}{k!} = (-1)^k (k+1).$$

However, I will retain the $\binom{-2}{k}$ notation to make it clear at the end where each term came from.

The first series converges everywhere while the second has a radius of convergence of $1$ (which is also asserted by the Binomial Theorem). Thus, for all $|t|\lt 1$ the subsequent manipulations will involve absolutely convergent power series (which therefore represent actual functions and not just formal power series).

Upon observing that $9\times 3^{-2}=1$ has no effect on the product, we may write the mgf in a more compact notation as

$$M_X(t) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-t)^n}{n!}\right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-2}{k} \left(\frac{2}{3}t\right)^k\right).$$

Expanding this product and collecting the terms in increasing powers of $t$ gives a neater expression, which is easily and automatically computed by calling the power $r$ (say), letting $k$ advance from $0$ through $r$, setting $n=r-k$, and multiplying a typical term of one sum by a typical term of the other:

$$M_X(t) = \sum_{r=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^r \frac{(-1)^{r-k}}{(r-k)!}\binom{-2}{k} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k\right)t^r.$$

Multiplying the coefficient of $t^r$ by $r!$ gives the associated moment:

$$\mathbb{E}(X^r) = (-1)^r r!\sum_{k=0}^r \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(r-k)!}\binom{-2}{k} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k = (-1)^r r!\sum_{k=0}^r \frac{k+1}{(r-k)!} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k.$$

I have factored out the terms depending only on $r$ and expanded the binomial coefficients $\binom{-2}{k}$, but that's as far as one can reasonably go: a "closed" formula would be expressed in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions, which (although useful for analysis) is, for the purpose of computing these moments, just a fancy way of disguising this summation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical calculus exercise where you need to figure out the $r$-th derivarive of a function, in this case $M_X(t)$. So you can follow the usual steps:

1) Derive up to some order (let say up to the third derivative) and figure out the pattern for the derivatives.

2) Conjecture a general form for the $r$-th derivative, let say $f(r)$, that is satisfied for indeed for $r=1,2,3$.

3) Derive the previous expression (so you will have the $r+1$-th derivative under your conjecture) and check if it coincides with the previous formula taking $r+1$ instead of $r$ (this is, $f(r+1)$). If yes, then you have the expression for the $r$-th derivative.

After you have the expression for $M_X^{(r)}(t)$ just evaluate it at $t=0$ to get the expressions for the moments $\mathbb{E}_X[X^r]$. You can start to think it with the first two derivatives of $M_X(t)$:

\begin{align}
M_X'(t)&=-\frac{36 e^{-t}}{(2 t+3)^3}-\frac{9 e^{-t}}{(2 t+3)^2},\\
M_X''(t)&=\frac{72 e^{-t}}{(2 t+3)^3}+\frac{216 e^{-t}}{(2 t+3)^4}+\frac{9 e^{-t}}{(2 t+3)^2}.
\end{align}

---

**EDIT**: This was answer was intended to provide the main guidelines for the exercise... but anyway since it seemed to be not clear enough, here are the expressions for the $r$-th derivatives of $M_X$.

First of all, to make the computations easier recall the following expression for the $r$-th derivative of the function $g(t)=e^{-t}h(t)$, which can be proved using steps 1)-3):
\begin{align}
g^{(r)}(t)=(-1)^re^{-t}\sum_{j=0}^r\binom{r}{j}(-1)^jh^{(j)}(t).
\end{align}
In our case, $h(t)=9(3+2t)^{-2}$ and the $j$-th derivatives of $h$ follow easily also, resulting
\begin{align}
h^{(j)}(t)=(-2)^j(j+1)!(2t+3)^{-(2+j)}.
\end{align}
Combining these two expressions, we have:
$$
M^{(r)}_X(t)=9(-1)^re^{-t}\sum_{j=0}^r\binom{r}{j}2^j(j+1)!(2t+3)^{-(2+j)}
$$
and the good point is that when $t=0$ we have
$$
\mathbb{E}_X[X^r]=M^{(r)}_X(0)=(-1)^r\sum_{j=0}^r\binom{r}{j}(j+1)!\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{j},
$$
which is exactly the final output that @guy has mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Have you gone through the calculations and verified this works? The simplest form I've managed to get is $E[X^r] = \sum_{j = 0} ^ r (-1)^j (2/3)^j (j + 1)! \binom{r}{j}$. Note also that it is $(3 + 2t)$, not $(2 + 2t)$ as you have.

Comment: You are right @guy about $(3+2t)$, stupid error. I edited the answer to fix it. I have not gone through the calculations, but the derivatives are correct.

Comment: So what reason is there to think that going through steps 1-3 will be fruitful? Unless my expression for $E[X^r]$ can be simplified substantially I don't see how one would hope to recognize it from looking at the first few term $-7/3, 19/3, -181/9, 2011/27$.

Comment: Should be $(-1)^r$, not $(-1)^j$ in the expression in my first comment.

Comment: OK, I will edit my answer to make it clearer. By the way, I will be glad to know another alternative solution.