# Characteristic function of distribution

Tags: self-study, moments, characteristic-function, taylor-series

$$p(x)=e^{-2 |x|}$$ with $x \in [-\infty, +\infty].$
I've calculated the characteristic function as $E[e^{ikx}]=\frac{1}{ik+2}-\frac{1}{ik-2}=\frac{4}{k^2+4}$. Now i'd like the moments.. so I suppose I should manipulate this expression in order to reduce it to a sum of infinite moments, but I can't!
Could you help me?

Comment: Note that you have called the characteristic function the moment generating function in your body text. The mgf is $M_X(t)=E(e^{tX})$ not $E(e^{itX})$; they're not identical. Secondly, you should simplify your characteristic function before playing with it further, and then see if you can write it as a power series.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: @Glen_b Ok, fixed question. But I still can't write it as power series. How should I proceed in these cases?

Comment: The mechanical way uses Taylor's theorem.  It's frequently the case that the Binomial theorem applies, as it does here: $$\frac{4}{k^2+4}=(1+(k^2/4))^{-1}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{-1}{i}\left(\frac{k^2}{4}\right)^i$$ provided $|k^2/4| \lt 1$.

Comment: @whuber thanks a lot but I've already did it.. the problem is that I can't get the moments... i should write it as the infinite sum of something * $\frac{(jk)^n}{n!}$ for n=0 to inf... that "something" will be the moment $\mu_n$..

Comment: If you have the expansion, you have the moments: simply inspect the coefficient of $k^n$ to find the $n^\text{th}$ moment (divided by $n!$, of course).

Comment: @whuber there's something I can't understand... the binomial theorem doesn't involve an *infinite* series...

Comment: It is my impression that odd raw moments are zero, while the integral for the even raw moments can be written as one of the simplest Merlin transforms. (cc: @whuber)

Comment: The Binomial Theorem has involved infinite series for more than 300 years.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem.  @Alecos: What is a "Merlin transform"?

Comment: @whuber Integrals of the form 

$$\int_0^{\infty} x^{z-1} f(z)dz$$ see eg. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html

Comment: @Alecos I thought perhaps you meant that: you needed to spell "Mellin" correctly.  But the connection to this problem is obscure, given that it's so simple to obtain the coefficients.

Comment: @whuber Ahahaha... Thanks whuber That made my day!

Comment: @whuber you're right, but sadly I wasn't taught about it! I have a problem dealing with binomial coefficients with negative numbers.. In particular I cannot understand why is this simplification http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/NegativeBinomialSeries/Inline7.gif in which I pull a (-1)^n out the binomial... could you help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: By definition, $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}.$$ That's all you need to obtain the moments, but if you want to see the actual coefficients, plug $-1$ in for $n$ to get $$\binom{-1}{k} = \frac{(-1)(-2)\cdots(-k)}{k!}=(-1)^k.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the nice things about characteristic and moment-generating functions is that you can (usually) read the moments right off of them.  You just have to expand them as MacLaurin series (Taylor series around zero).  In this answer I use the techniques described at [How to compute moments from an MGF explicitly](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119712) and therefore will refer interested readers to that thread for more information.

This one is handled easily with the [Binomial Theorem:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem)

$$\frac{4}{k^2+4}=(1+(k^2/4))^{-1}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{-1}{j}\left(\frac{k^2}{4}\right)^j = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j(2j)!}{2^{2j}}\frac{k^{2j}}{(2j)!}.$$

To achieve the expression at the right I used $$\binom{-1}{j} = \frac{(-1)(-2)\cdots(-j)}{j!}=(-1)^j$$ and I also inserted a factor of $$\frac{(2j)!}{(2j)!}=1$$ so that the general term in the sum would be in the form

$$(i)^n\mu_n \frac{k^n}{n!}$$

where, evidently, $n=2j$ must be an even number and $i=\sqrt{-1}$.  We see, without any further calculation, that

$$\mu_n = \frac{n!}{2^n}.$$

This is the $n^\text{th}$ raw moment. All odd moments are zero.

---

It's always a good idea to check one's work if possible.  To this end, note that some values of the even moments are

$$\matrix{
\text{n}&\mu_n \\
0 & \frac{0!}{2^0} = 1 \\
2 & \frac{2!}{2^2} = \frac{1}{2} \\
4 & \frac{4!}{2^4} = \frac{3}{2}
}$$

(I am in the habit of computing the zeroth moment--which is the total probability, always equal to $1$--as a check of the formula.)

These agree with the values for $b=\sqrt{4}=2$ listed in the [Wikipedia entry for the Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution).  In particular, the "excess kurtosis" is given by

$$\kappa_4 = \frac{\mu_4}{\mu_2^2}-3 = \frac{3/2}{(1/2)^2} - 3 = 6-3 = 3,$$

exactly as claimed.

Comment: Unexpected idea: isn't the geometric expansion enough (instead of binomial)?

Comment: @Surfer Yes, that's correct (and elegant).  I like to cite the Binomial Theorem because for many people *that* is the unexpected result--and it is far more general.